# When to use self in module's methods

Tags: ruby, self

My module definition looks like this:

```
module RG::Stats
  def self.sum(a, args = {})
    a.inject(0){ |accum, i| accum + i }
  end
end
```

To use this method I simply require the file containing this definition so that I can do:

```
RG::Stats.sum(array)
```

and also

```
RG::Stats.method(:sum)
```

However, if I need to know the list of methods using `RG::Stats.instance_methods` I get an empty array. This is because I have used `self`. If I omit `self` then `RG::Stats.instance_methods` gives the list of methods, but I cannot access them anymore.

The question is: how to use `self` in module's method definition?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `self` in each method definition if you want the methods to be defined only in the singleton class of the module (where the methods defined using `self` live). Omit self and `extend self` if you want the methods of the module to be defined as instance methods and singleton methods at the same time.

For instance, you can call the method using `RG::Stats.sum(array)` and still have it listed by the `instance_methods` method if you do this:

```
module RG::Stats
  extend self

  def sum(a, args = {})
    a.inject(0){ |accum, i| accum + i }
  end
end
```

This way, the `sum` method is defined as an instance method and it is included in the singleton class  of the module after using `extend self`.

You can check the instance methods of `RG::Stats` module to verify this:

```
RG::Stats.instance_methods
=> [:sum]
```

With this technique you don't have to worry about defining the method without the `self` keyword because modules can't have instances so it cannot be called like an instance method of `RG::Stats` module. It can only be called as a singleton method `RG::Stats.sum(array)` thanks to the `extend self` statement.

Answer (score 6):

If you use `self`, then you can use the module method directly using: `RG::Stats.sum(array)` as you mentioned above.

If you don't use `self` to define the method inside your module, then the method will be included as `instance_method` for a class where you include the module.

So, you can define the `sum` instance method inside your `RG::Stats` module:

```
module RG::Stats
  def sum(a, args = {})
    a.inject(0){ |accum, i| accum + i }
  end
end
```

Then, you can include `RG::Stats` module inside a class and then the `sum` method will be available as a `instance_method` for objects of the class:

```
class YourClass
  include RG::Stats

  . . .
  . . .
end
```

And you can call the `sum` method on an instance of `YourClass`:
    YourClass.new.sum

To answer your question, you can use `self` to define your method as a class method inside your module, and without `self` to define the method as instance method and it depends on your need and usecase that when you want what type of behaviour from your module methods.

Answer (score 3):

It is because `def self.sum` does not define an instance method; you are using the wrong method to select it. Try this instead:

```
RG::Stats.methods(false)
# => [:sum]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Class: RuboCop::Cop::Style::ModuleFunction` rule recommends to use module_function to make all methods self.

ref: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/ModuleFunction

```
# bad
module Test
  extend self
  # ...
end

# good
module Test
  module_function
  # ...
end
```